# What do I need to add to my AndroidManifest.xml to have this intent open my app?

Tags: android, android-intent

There is an app launching this intent, it already has my package name in there but my app never opens.

```
I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=rtmp://ip swfUrl=http://ip/jwplayer.flash.swf live=1 token=�ey(nKa@ typ=video/* pkg=mypackage} from uid 10080 on display 0
```

In my app I already have:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:scheme="rtmp"/>
            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:scheme="rtmp"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

and:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
   <data android:mimeType="video/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

So why is my app never started?

Thanks.

EDIT: other share intents out of the same app works just fine, for example this one:

`I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://ip/master.m3u8?b?b*t$ typ=video/* pkg=mypackage cmp=mypackage/.MyActivity} from uid 10080 on display 0`

Comment: Intents are tied to activites, where are the intent-filters defined? Can you provide more of your manifest

Comment: They are defined inside my activity. I should point out they work fine for most other apps sharing with my app. For example this one coming out of the same app works just fine `I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://ip/master.m3u8?b?b*t$ typ=video/* pkg=mypackage cmp=mypackage/.MyActivity} from uid 10080 on display 0`